# angularjs on form edit select option does not load value On Second Time

Tags: angularjs

My form has got 2 select boxes. The second select options box is loaded when an option is selected in first box. The form is used for both adding and editing. I show the list below the form with edit button against each row. When I click on edit button it loads the values in form to edit. The thing is when I click on a row for first time it loads the values in form perfectly. If I click on another row button to edit, the SECOND select option alone does not show the selected value. But the box is loaded with values.

**Code in controller:**

```
     $scope.editShift = function(row) {
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.availableShift.length; i++) {
                if ($scope.availableShift[i].shiftId === row.entity.shiftId) {
                    $scope.shift = angular.copy($scope.availableShift[i]);
                    break;
                };
            }; 
            $scope.selectLineNames();
        };


    $scope.selectLineNames = function(){
        $scope.availableListOfLineNames = [];
        $scope.availableListOfLineNamesTemp = LineDetails.ld_get_ln_resource.query
                           ({plant: $scope.shift.plant}, function(response) {
        angular.forEach(response, function(item) {
        if (item) {
                    $scope.availableListOfLineNames.push(item);
                }
            });
        });
    };
```

**Second Select Option in Form**

```
<select name="lineName" ng-model="shift.lineName" 
  ng-options="x for x in availableListOfLineNames" id="selectoption2" required>
 <option value="">Select One</option>
</select>
```

**EDIT:**

Calling `$scope.selectLineNames();` inside `$scope.editShift` somehow makes the `lineName` value `undefined` after copy, on second time. Inside `selectLineNames()`  too the value is available until it reaches the `forEach()` .Only after the loop starts It becomes `undefined`.

So used a duplicate method like `$scope.selectLineNamesTemp();` and passed values from `$scope.editShift` and assigned them in the duplicate method like below.

```
    $scope.selectLineNamesTemp = function(){
                    $scope.availableListOfLineNames = [];
                $scope.availableListOfLineNamesTemp = LineDetails.ld_get_ln_resource.query(
{plant: plantTemp}, function(response) {
                    angular.forEach(response, function(item) {
                        if (item) {
                            $scope.availableListOfLineNames.push(item);
                            $scope.shift.lineName = lnTemp; // assigned from editShift
                        }
                    });
                }) ;
                };
```

Can someone point out why the value become undefined? Also is there a way to use the same old method without using the duplicate method. Hope someone help.

Comment: Please include your view code as well as the definition of `selectLineNames` as well as any other artefacts that are involved in the behavior you are describing.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in a fiddler?

Comment: I have updated the code. Please check.

Comment: Why it loads with selected value on first time and not on second time? What could be major reason behind the issue? Can someone suggest me some ideas to check.

Comment: Add plunker/jsfiddle or other tool to demo behavior

Comment: possible issue of the second selected could by coming from the response. could you set a debugger right before code '$scope.availableListOfLineNames.push(item);' (make sure that the second select also trigger the debugger inside the if scope.
as suggest by others plunker/jsfiddle will be helpful to solve your problem.

Comment: @mtamma  Okay will check now. I could not recreate it on jsfiddle. will try again.

Comment: @mtamma  you are right. At the second time lineName is undefined in $scope.shift.plant. It holds all the other values. What should i do?

Comment: @mtamma  lineName value is undefined in $scope.shift inside editShift()

Comment: @user7620991 which element triggering editShift function?
somehow ($scope.availableShift[i].shiftId === row.entity.shiftId) did not match. it's hard to guessing sir. try to print (console.log()) row value on editShift function.

Comment: @mtamma  I am trying to make the jsfiddle work. Will post if possible. I using a gyphicon in <a> to trigger the function. that statement you pointed is matching. i get the values there. in  ' $scope.shift = angular.copy($scope.availableShift[i]); '  too i am able to get the value for  '$scope.availableShift[i] ' . For  ' $scope.shift '  log shows all values like resource{ }. But if i expand the resourse the lineName variable is undefined.

Comment: One final suggestion please. What could be the possible reason for the variable to become undefined while angular.copy()? As i said in above comment resource{}  says the values is there but when i expand it, inside it the lineName is undefined.